# Can i boot my laptop with external dvd writer?

Tags: boot, optical-drive, dvd-burning

My Laptop DVD writer is not reading drives any more, so I thought rather than buying a new internal, I should get new external writer.

The only thing I will be using that is to boot the Laptop or PC for re-installation of OS oe running Anti virus BOOT CDS.

I want to know how much will the performance issue.

Will the OS installtion will be slow with external DVD writer?

Comment: Just FYI, it would probably be both cheaper and faster to use a USB flash drive instead of an external DVD drive.

Comment: Did you get this to work?  I have not found a dvd drive that I can boot off of successfully.

Comment: @William no,  i had to get bootaable USB drive

Comment: @Moorage then you should probably change the accepted answer.  In my experience I have not found a way to boot of a usb external cd/dvd drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Make sure that you have enabled in BIOS the option to **boot from other devices** and **adjust the boot order** so that the dvd drive is accessed before the hard drive.

Performance wise, it depends on the speed of the dvd drive and the speed of the usb port you plug it into, but generally speaking, today I presume that your laptop has USB 2 ports and that would be a more than decent speed (30Mb/s maximum), therefore the bottleneck should actually be the reading speed of the dvd drive (aproximately 1,3Mb for each 1x .. that would be 13Mb/s at 10x read speed)

Comment: I want to know what speed should be good for writing a DVD mostly I used 16x or 24x.

Comment: +1 For 1x and about its speed it will help the question owner to know the speed of Drive. Our answers were matching so you edited your. Nice work buddy.

Comment: @avirk : I remember back in the CD writing days, in some cases, if you wrote a CD at 48x and then you wanted to read it in a older max 24x reader it did not always work. I'm not sure if it also applies to DVDs but I know that as a good practice, if you want to make sure you have a good lasting and compatible DVD you should not write at very fast speeds

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine, I have done exactly that for installing various versions of windows and linux. It's not significantly slower than an internal drive.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found an external cd/dvd drive that supports booting cd/dvds.  I hope I am wrong but this has been my experience.  Although I don't appreciate the downvotes I have tested this on multiple (like 5) external cd/dvd drives and they simple don't work as a boot volume.

Answer (score 0):

It depends data transfer rate of the external DVD driver...
It may be slower but you can do whatever you do as your other driver sources.